# What is the difference between New-Object -ComObject in Powershell and CreateObject() in VB?

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have a question about how Windows PowerShell works when dealing with Com Interop.

I have a 3rd party application (let's call it `ThirdPartyApp`) that exposes an API that I can call into.

I can early-bind it in e.g. Excel or Visual Studio and talk to it 'directly'. I can late-bind it in VBScript and still talk to it 'directly'.

By 'directly' I mean the way I can call properties and methods exposed by the API using syntax like `ThirdPartyApp.Name`

So in VBScript I can do:

```
Dim api : Set api = CreateObject("ThirdPartyApp.API")
WScript.Echo api.Name
```

In PowerShell, when I do:

```
$api =  New-Object -ComObject ThirdPartyApp.API
```

I have to use this syntax to get the Name:

```
[System.__ComObject].InvokeMember('Name',[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty,$null,$api,$null)
```

Now, I understand that that has something to do with how `ThirdPartyApp` was built.

I know this isn't a coding problem, and I hope I don't get downvoted immediately, but my question is: why can't I talk to this assembly the VBScript way when using Powershell? How does `New-Object -ComObject` in Powershell differ from `CreateObject(identifier)` in VBScript?

Comment: Please update the question to clarify if you're using Windows PowerShell or PowerShell [Core].

Comment: Done. It is about Windows Powershell. It's about COM, that's Windows-only right? But okay.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. PowerShell [Core] runs on Windows too, and its COM support is lacking in certain areas, hence my question. Based on the guidance for tag 'powershell', Windows PowerShell would be implied - 'powershell-core' is recommended for PowerShell [Core] questions, but I suspect this line will increasingly be blurred as PowerShell [Core] takes over.

Answer (score 0):

**Information for Visual Basic Programmers**

Visual Basic provides full support for Automation. The following table lists how Visual Basic statements translate into OLE APIs.

**Visual Basic statement OLE APIs**

**CreateObject (“ProgID”)**

- CLSIDFromProgID
- CoCreateInstance
- QueryInterface to get IDispatch interface.

**GetObject (“filename”, “ProgID”)**

- CLSIDFromProgID
- CoCreateInstance
- QueryInterface for IPersistFile interface.
- Load on IPersistFile interface.
- QueryInterface to get IDispatch interface.

**GetObject (“filename”)**\

- CreateBindCtx creates the bind context for the subsequent functions.
- MkParseDisplayName returns a moniker handle for BindMoniker.
- BindMoniker returns a pointer to the IDispatch interface.
- Release on moniker handle.
- Release on context.

**GetObject (“ProgID”)**

- CLSIDFromProgID
- GetActiveObject on class ID.
- QueryInterface to get IDispatch interface.

**Dim x As New interface**

- Find CLSID for interface.
- CoCreateInstance
- QueryInterface

MSDN Library October 2001 Microsoft Corp.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/

Comment: thank you for that information but that doesn't cover the PowerShell bit

Comment: Because I want to understand the difference, hence both tags.

Comment: And I thanked you for that. The question that still puzzles me is if 'QueryInterface to get IDispatch interface' in VB suffices to enable a 'direct' call to a member in that interface, why do I (sometimes, depending on the application) have to use the rather convoluted syntax in Powershell?

Comment: Perhaps your question is a .NET question which powershell uses. .NET wraps COM classes in .NET classes and vice versa. And to a BASIC programmer their is no difference. The same or similar code in any MS Basic, as VB.NET is more strict, works identically. Perhaps you should be asking to powershell people how does PS implement the calls - its an advanced and intricate subject, which I won't pontificate on..