# When using VBScript to open Excel workbook in the background, how to open another workbook at the same time?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have converted a VBA program that is used to delete unwanted rows to VBScript because I wanted to execute the program in the background, and in the meantime I can open another workbook to do something else. (If written in VBA first I have to open the workbook and run the Macro instead of just double click the icon and run, second I cannot work with any other excel workbook until the Macro finishes, during this time the excel application will just be frozen)

Below is my program, it worked fine if I do not open another workbook. The point is actually how to keep it run in the background so that in the same time I can work on another workbook. If I opened another workbook, the "abc.xlsx" also appears in the task bar, and then some run time error, however, in my program, every excel object are properly refereced to the worksheet in "abc.xlsx".

I have tried things like: objExcel.Visible = False and objExcel.ScreenUpdating = False, but unfortunately didn't work.

```
Dim FilePatch, objExcel, xlApp, wb, ws
FilePath = "C:\abc.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.ScreenUpdating = False

Set xlApp = objExcel.Application
Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)

Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

const xlDown = -4121
Dim nr, Amt, n, i
nr = ws.Range("K1").End(xlDown).Row
Amt = ws.Range("K2:K" & nr).Value

For i = 2 To nr
    If Amt(i - 1, 1) = 0 Then
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next

Dim breakinto, multiple

breakinto = 500

remainder = n Mod breakinto
multiple = Int(n / breakinto)

Dim rng, Z(), j, k

For k = 1 To multiple + 1

    nr = ws.Range("K1").End(xlDown).Row
    Amt = ws.Range("K2:K" & nr).Value

    n = 0
    Erase Z

    For i = 2 To nr
        If Amt(i - 1, 1) = 0 Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve Z(n)
            Z(n) = i
        End If
    Next

    Set rng = ws.Rows(Z(1))

    If k = multiple + 1 Then
        For j = 2 To remainder
            Set rng = Xlapp.Union(rng, ws.Rows(Z(j)))
        Next
        rng.Delete
    Else
        For j = 2 To breakinto
            Set rng = Xlapp.Union(rng, ws.Rows(Z(j)))
        Next
        rng.Delete
    End If

Next

wb.Close True

objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing

MsgBox "Completed"

WScript.Quit
```

Please let me know what to modify in order to run this in the background that does not interfer with another opened workbook (as a seperate instance of excel applicaion). Thanks all!

Comment: Use `GetObject("Filename")` to get references to an excel workbook..

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Could you let me know what’s the difference between GetObject and Workbooks.Open to open a workbook? I’ve seen other people wrote GetObject and it can open workbook, but don’t actually see the difference/advantage of using it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61178839/what-is-the-difference-between-new-object-comobject-in-powershell-and-createobj

Comment: You want to open a file but you are creating an application. Then Copying this App object for an unknown reason. `GetObject("Fname!sheetname")` **switches to that file if open, or opens the file if not already opened**.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this (Excel 365, Win10)  If I start a hidden instance of Excel and add a workbook it stays hidden, even if I then launch Excel from the taskbar and open a different file.  The file from the hidden instance doesn't show up in the second (visible) instance.

Test script:

```
Dim objExcel, xlApp, wb, ws, c

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = false
Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.add()
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
Set c = ws.range("A1")

'loop while staying hidden for about 30sec, then switch to visible
Do 
    c.value = "Hello"
    Set c = c.offset(1,0)
    If c.row > 10 Then
        xlApp.Visible = True
        Exit Do
    End If

    WScript.Sleep(3000) 'msec
Loop
```

Even when the hidden instance becomes visible and the vbscript exits, they are still two separate instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was using Excel 2007, Win 7 and had this problem. Later I tried on another PC with Excel 365 and Win 10, seems fine... That's so weird. Using Excel 2007 and Win 7, if I open another workbook after starting to run this program, the hidden instance will show up, and my newly opened workbook became very slow, and then run time error at some point... Also, some workbooks opened were fine, but some shared the same Excel application with the created instance... Not sure if that's Excel 2007's problem.